# binance python api margin order incomplete repay loan

Tags: python, margin, quotes, cryptocurrency, binance

I am trying to repay a loan using the binance python API. I retrieve the loan size from the acct dictionary and input that as the quoteOrderQty in the auto repay margin order.

When I run closeLong() the loan is not paid off completely, a small balance remains in the base and a small USDT debt remains in the quote. What am I doing wrong here?

```
acct = client.get_isolated_margin_account()
def quoteDebt():
    quoteLoan = round(Decimal(acct['assets'][1]['quoteAsset']['borrowed']),2)
    print("USDT Debt: "+str(quoteLoan))
    return quoteLoan

def closeLong():
    client.create_margin_order(
        symbol=sym,
        side=SIDE_SELL,
        type=ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
        sideEffectType= 'AUTO_REPAY', 
        isIsolated='TRUE',
        quoteOrderQty=quoteDebt())  
    print("Closed Long")
```

Comment: do you have any updates? I have same problem in NodeJS binance api client

Comment: @DmitriyYurov Have you been able to resolve this issue ? Also, how do you know the value of the interest fee you have to pay ? I also use Node Binance client

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue. I believe it's that interest is compounded continuously, so a tiny amount of interest is incurred between you checking how much is owed and you repaying it. I hacked around this by looping indefinitely: the first loop repays the principal, the second the interest on that, the third the interest on *that*, and by the 4th or 5th loop the interest rounds down to 0. I'd much prefer if there were a repay_all() API call available, of course, but I'm not aware of anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, not nice from Binance to not enable us to fully repay automatically through API. If you can lock some extra amount on this, ideal solution for me is to buy the borrowed asset on spot account, fees are paid from BNB, which is less vs. isolated margin account, transfer the asset to isolated margin account a repay (2 step approach). You need to have the reserve though, as you can't transfer all money out of margin account, when in position, as it will get liquidated.

If you try to repay isolated account directly, 0.1% fee is deducted, so the loan is not fully repaid. If buy from spot, you can pay fee as 0.075% in BNB and get the full amount of asset you asked for (as fees are paid in BNB). No tiny amounts remaining.

Ideal approach for you, is based on frequency of trades. High frequency trading - fees matters, trades are small and you can allocate extra funds to this. Low frequency trading - fees does not matter that much, you might want to go all-in, not having extra funds, and you might do this manually as well ("Close all positions" in UI), for those tiny amounts...